# sqlite constraint failed error code

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

I have two tables albums and songs and each song has reference to alum's id.

Album table :

```
CREATE TABLE albums
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
name TEXT,
additional TEXT)
```

Song table:

```
CREATE TABLE songs
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
album_fk INTEGER NOT NULL,
title TEXT,
url TEXT,
duration BIGINT NOT NULL)
```

and i also have a trigger to check when i delete an album if there are existing songs in it :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON albums
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT RAISE(FAIL,'album has songs cannot be deleted')
WHERE (SELECT album_fk FROM songs WHERE album_fk = OLD.id) IS NOT
NULL;)
END
```

all this is working fine but sometimes

```
Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error
code 19: constraint failed
Stack Trace :
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:
66)
```

is thrown when i try to delete an album. My delete method is simply deleting an album by id.The bad thing is that i can't reproduce this so there is no much info i can provide. 
I tried different scenarios with deleting an album but i never got this exception.

So any ideas how can investigate this issue. There are not any contraints in album table so what could cause such exception ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, I would recommend you to download SQLite database browser. This software offers the possibility to test your queries after exporting them from the emulator. This way you can check if there is any error. Moreover, just after you raise function, you have a ; but it seems to cut your query in the middl because it is followed by a where

Comment: The first time you created your table , was it without any constraints as it is in your post? If you run for the first time with constraints, the table will be created. Then if you remove the constraint and re-run your project, the table will not be recreated (if you just use getWrtiableDatabase()) and you will have the old version (with constraint). So you will have to delete it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so not fair. If you run this code on PC everything is OK and if you try to delete album that has songs the exception says :album has songs cannot be deleted" but it seems that android guys don't handle correct RAISE from sqlite and jsut throw Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by correcting the definition of my database to a field that is NOT NULL. You must send some data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some triggers in the backgroung, I finally switched to this classic option and it fixed my problem:

db.rawQuery("UPDATE table set column = newValue WHERE ... ;", null);

Answer (score 0):

See also "SQLiteStatement does not propagate error messages defined in SQLite triggers"
 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3296